# Multi-level Generics

Tags: java, class, generics

I am trying to write a class as:

```
public class Article<T<? extends ManageGenericArticleInDTO>, U> implements Serializable {
    private T<? extends ManageGenericArticleInDTO> userInput;
    private U severData;

    public Article<T<? extends ManageGenericArticleInDTO>, U>() {
        super();
    }


    public void setUserInput(T<? extends ManageGenericArticleInDTO> userInput) {
        this.userInput = userInput;
    }

    public T<? extends ManageGenericArticleInDTO> getUserInput() {
        return userInput;
    }

    public void setSeverData(U severData) {
        this.severData = severData;
    }

    public U getSeverData() {
        return severData;
    }
}
```

So that I can write these:

```
Article<UpdateManageArticleInDTO<ManageGenericArticleInDTO>, UpdateCentralPOSMArticleDTO> article = new Article<UpdateManageArticleInDTO<ManageGenericArticleInDTO>, UpdateCentralPOSMArticleDTO>();
Article<AddManageArticleInDTO<ManageCentralPOSMArticleInDTO>, AddArticleStepDTO> article = new Article<AddManageArticleInDTO<ManageCentralPOSMArticleInDTO>, AddArticleStepDTO>(); // ManageCentralPOSMArticleInDTO extends ManageGenericArticleInDTO
```

I am getting compilation error that `Error(7,32):  > expected`, `Error(7,33):  illegal start of type` etc. In my understanding the Type reference will be replaced by the actual class., Can't I define the class in this?

---

If I do this:

```
public class AddArticleInBean<T, U> implements Serializable {
    private T userInput;
    private U severData;

    public AddArticleInBean() {
        super();
    }


    public void setUserInput(T userInput) {
        this.userInput = userInput;
    }

    public T getUserInput() {
        return userInput;
    }

    public void setSeverData(U severData) {
        this.severData = severData;
    }

    public U getSeverData() {
        return severData;
    }
}
```

This errors are not anymore appearing, but I am getting warning that T and U are non-serializable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing opening and closing brackets

It should be,

```
Article<UpdateManageArticleInDTO<ManageGenericArticleInDTO>, UpdateCentralPOSMArticleDTO> article = new Article<UpdateManageArticleInDTO<ManageGenericArticleInDTO>, UpdateCentralPOSMArticleDTO>();
Article<AddManageArticleInDTO<ManageCentralPOSMArticleInDTO>, AddArticleStepDTO> article = new Article<AddManageArticleInDTO<ManageCentralPOSMArticleInDTO>, AddArticleStepDTO>();
```

Comment: I getting the compilation error in the definition of the class. The missing parenthesis is due to writing in Notepad.

Comment: following code should fix the warnings : public class AddArticleInBean<T extends Serializable, U extends Serializable> implements Serializable {
    private T userInput;
    private U severData;

    public AddArticleInBean() {
        super();
    }


    public void setUserInput(T userInput) {
        this.userInput = userInput;
    }

    public T getUserInput() {
        return userInput;
    }

    public void setSeverData(U severData) {
        this.severData = severData;
    }

    public U getSeverData() {
        return severData;
    }
}